# multiple IP addresses, chooce the sender

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

I have eth0 and eth1. I am creating a simple tcp program with gsoap. the endpoint is 1.2.3.4.

The endpoint receives my data, but the IP of eth0 is shown in the sender details. I would like my receiver to see eth1 instead of eth0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) call to select the source IP, or create an explicit [`route(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) to the server via `eth1`. Second option is probably preferable since you don't need to modify the client source code.

Comment: Yes, or create a route to the server via `eth1`.

Comment: Nikolai, bind needs an IP and a port. How do I select the port? How do I know if it is available or not?

Comment: Set the port to `0`, the kernel will select an available ephemeral port for you.

Comment: does the route(8) works both ways? do I need to add a route from eth1 to eth0 for the reply from the server?

Comment: That's the upstream router job to route through appropriate link on the way back. Usual setup for non-router machines is to have a single *default* route that all traffic follows.